# UK Visitor Visa from USA- Qn regarding courier to New York

Tags: visas, usa, uk

My husband I are applying for a Standard UK Visitor Visa from USA and we booked the Bio metrics. We have filled Individual Applications, but should we send the applications separately to the New York Consulate?

Also should we take the Premium Services offered in the VFS site? It looks pretty steep for a courier to New York.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dispute between US and UK that even if you have a confirmed biometric appointment, when you show up at the center they will notify you that..

https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/news/update-on-service-disruption-message-from-uk-visas-immigration

Uk and check this forum and you will find other info. Root cause maybe as reported here

https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/apr/16/bureaucratic-glitch-uk-suspends-visa-enrollment-for-american-citizens